# Line breaks in subfig

Tags: line-breaking, subfloats

I'm trying to put some text in a subfloat using the subfig package.  (It's supposed to be part of the figure, not the caption.)  I can't figure out how to add a line break.  When I try this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \subfloat[a]{A\\\texttt{This is a test}}
  \subfloat[b]{B}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I get the error:
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

I tried changing the `\\` to `\linebreak`, `\newline`, and `\par`.  They all either do nothing or give an error.  I also tried wrapping the text in an `mbox`, and I tried putting the line break inside the `texttt`.  Nothing works.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you enclose your text in `\shortstack{...}`, you'll get the line breaks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \subfloat[a]{\shortstack{A\\\texttt{This is a test}}}
  \subfloat[b]{B}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The alignment can be adjusted using the optional argument. `\shortstack[l]{...}` will align your text on the left, `\shortstack[r]{...}` on the right.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `\mbox` allows line breaks. You could put the text in a `\parbox` which does allow like breaks as in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \subfloat[a]{\parbox{2.0in}{A\\\texttt{This is a test}}}
  \subfloat[b]{B}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, but I want to avoid manually specifying a width.