# Line break between two graphics in a subfig-style subfloat

Tags: line-breaking, subfloats

What I am trying to achieve is this:

```
AA B
AA C
```

A being one subfigure, B+C a second. However, I don't achieve the line break between B and C:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{mwe}
%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \subfloat[]{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.6666\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
        \subfloat[]{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.3333\linewidth]{example-image-b}\\
            \includegraphics[width=0.3333\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It basically looks like this:

```
AA 
AA BC
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: either of the first two links in the related list on the right shows how to force a linebreak in subfig

Comment: The second one is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125287/ and the answer is about the `subcaption` package.

Comment: The first one is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31420 and recommends using `\shortstack`. However, changing `\\ ` into `\shortstack{\\}` gives `Misplaced \cr`.

Comment: it means `\shortstack{\includegraphics{} \\ \includegraphics{}}` (it is just a form of compressed tabular)

Comment: Oh, I incorrectly assumed `\shortstack` was for text only. Thanks, much simpler than a table or a minipage!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{mwe}
%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \subfloat[]{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.6666\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
        \subfloat[]{\begin{tabular}[b]{c}%
            \includegraphics[width=0.3333\linewidth]{example-image-b}\\            
            \includegraphics[width=0.3333\linewidth]{example-image-c}
                    \end{tabular}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It seems that inside `subfloat` is not possible to break line, so I put both figures in tabular` environment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The spacing is not optimal, but maybe a `minipage` will improve that.

Comment: @bers, I didn't bother with spacing, but it can be done also with use of tabular. horizontal distance between A and B you can set with `\hspace {<length>} ` or `hfil` between subfloats, vertical distance between image `b` and `c` with  `\\[<length>] after first row of table. To set the same height ... you can guess image with which will give desired height of image or, more complex approach, first you measure of height of right subfloat and than with it adjust height of image in the lest subfloat.